# The term 'Connect-AzAccount' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

This code is working in my local machine in Powershell ISE, but it is not working in the devops pipeline

```
$AzureTenantId = "dgfg"
$AzureApplicationId = "fgfgg"
$AzureApplicationSecret = "fdgfghf"

$SecuredApplicationSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString "$AzureApplicationSecret" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AzureApplicationId , $SecuredApplicationSecret)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $AzureTenantId -ServicePrincipal
```

I am getting this error:
The term 'Connect-AzAccount' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

What changes I need to need to do so that it also works in the pipeline?

Comment: @wade zhou - MSFT - kindly check if you can help me with this issue

Comment: Just use azure powershell instead of the normal powershell in a pipeline. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Pipelines, it is recommended using the [Azure PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines) to execute the Azure PowerShell commands.

And use an ARM service connection ([**Azure Resource Manager service connection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-resource-manager-service-connection)) on the task to safety connect to Azure.

---